# NextJS fails to call my backend node app for multi containerization of services

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, next.js, docker-compose

I am trying to learn `docker`. I have a `next.js` app and a `node.js` app.

In my `next.js` app, in page.tsx I am calling my backend api

```
export const revalidate = 0;

export default async function Home() {
  const response = await fetch("/api/getRandomNumber");
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <h1>{data.lastInfo.randomNumber}</h1>
    </main>
  );
}
```

In `nodejs` I have just created an endpoint `getRandomNumber` with `expressjs`

```
router.get("/getRandomNumber", async (req, res) => {
  const randNumber = `${Math.random() * 100}`;
  const info = new Info({ randomNumber: randNumber });
  await info.save();
  const lastInfo = await Info.findOne({
    where: { randomNumber: randNumber },
  });

  return res.status(200).send({ lastInfo });
});
```

I know `next.js` is a full stack framework, but here I am trying to learn how to dockerize multiple services so created separate `node.js` app

Below is my docker file for next.js app

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./ ./

CMD ["npm","run","dev"]
```

Below is my docker file for `node.js` app

```
FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY ./ ./

CMD ["npm","run","dev"]
```

Next I want to use nginx so I created a folder for it and inside it I created `default.conf` and `Dockerfile.dev`

In `default.conf`

```
upstream nextapp {
    server nextapp:3000;
}

upstream nodeapp {
    server nodeapp:3001;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://nextapp;
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://nodeapp;
    }

    location /ws {
      proxy_pass http://nextapp;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
  }
}
```

So I am appending /api to my nodejs app via default.conf

In `Dockerfile.dev`

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

Then one `docker-compose.yml` file for `next.js`, `nginx` and `node.js`

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres_password
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "3050:80"
    depends_on:
      - nodeapp
      - nextapp
  nodeapp:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nodeapp
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules #don't try to override this folder
      - ./nodeapp:/app
    environment:
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres_password
      - PGPORT=5432
  nextapp:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nextapp
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./nextapp:/app
    environment:
      - WDS_SOCKET_PORT=0
```

I am able to see my `node.js` app on `http://localhost:3050/api/getRandomNumber` but in my next.js app I get error when I try to call the node.js api. If I comment out the fetch call in my next.js app it works fine on `http://localhost:3050/`

If I try to call `http://localhost:3050/api/getRandomNumber` in fetch I get error saying Error: fetch failed

[image]

If I try to call just  `/api/getRandomNumber` in fetch I get error saying Failed to parse url

[image]

Github repo [here](https://github.com/kyadalu1/MultiContainerServiceSample)

More screenshot

[image]

Comment: When you do `await fetch("/api/getRandomNumber");` you're calling `localhost` inside the container, not your `nginx` container.

Comment: @KevinKopf Not sure what you mean, so I use my IP instead of localhost? If yes is it possible to not hardcode the domain in my nextjs app given the nodejs app runs on the same port? The port will keep changing

Comment: Your containers are not using your host network, they are on their own (separated) network. You may try running them with `network_mode: host`. Or use the container names to connect between them. Also without further debugging info it's impossible to tell what `fetch failed` stands for. You need to check your console.

Comment: I checked my console. I have no idea what is the issue. I have attached screenshot in the question. I did try without docker and it works but in that case my node app is on 3001 and I had to pass entire url to my next app as it is on 3000

Comment: 1. `Failed to parse URL from /api/getRandomNumber` 2. "I have no idea what is the issue"...............................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `fetch()` in NextJS server-side, you have to use the full URL.
So it should be something like `fetch('http://localhost:3050/api/getRandomNumber')`.

By default compose creates a network and all the containers joins to that. But if you update your code to use localhost as base URL you will get an ECONNREFUSED error. It is because `localhost` is not understoodable in context of docker - it points to the containers inner network.

So what docker can understand is the service name. If you put the service name there as base url, then it will work.

Here is the updated code:

```
const response = await fetch("http://nginx/api/getRandomNumber", { method: 'GET' });
```

Of course this is not something i'd go to production with. At least the base URL should be an env variable.
And in production you wont run the containers in compose i think, normally those should be standalone EC2/S or Droplet instances.

Comment: Thanks. Can you help elaborate 1. why we are using http://nginx/api/getRandomNumber instead of http://nodeapp/api/getRandomNumber 2. I just started learning docker and was following Stephen graders udemy course , should I put my actual domain in env 3. I didn't get why can't I run containers in compose in production for EC2

Comment: 1. Based on my understanding your nginx server behaves like a proxy server. So its a ery good pattern to call your proxy and it will forward the request to the proper place.
Of course, you can use your API directly, but is has no port mappings (at least in your GH repo), so i'm not sure if you can call it from the next application.

2. Yes always, put any of your domains, URLs to env files - they are 100% environment related, may change per environment.

3. OFC compose can be used in production, but it will run on a single machine. What means its scalability capacity is not that good.

Comment: So I should learn Kubernetes